# Child theme file not override to parent theme files

Tags: wordpress

I have to development wordpress child theme for catch-everest theme. There are some file in inc folder. That files not override in child theme. I want override a javascript file. How can I do it?
Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 1):

You will most likely need to find where the javascript or CSS is enqueued in the parent theme, then in your child theme remove those actions with `remove_action`. Then, you need to enqueue the javascript of your own using `add_action`.

This way you are removing theirs and replacing with yours.

See Wordpress Codex [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action)

NOTE: If your parent theme does not fully support children, and does not enqueue javascript correctly, this method may not work (probably won't). In this case you will likely have to override the javascript with more javascript.